# Xamarin : UISearchController is not becoming first responder and editing is not getting started while adding it to Navigation Bar

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin.ios

I am facing a strange issue with `UISearchController`.
I have added the search controller in Navigation Bar in UIViewController1 on click of a button. It is working fine in UIViewController1. Now I am navigating to UIViewController2 and there also I am adding the UISearchController on click of a button. Below is the sample code. The problem is that in UIViewController2 UISearchController is not becoming first responder and `OnEditingStarted` is not getting fired. It is happening when I have used (added search controller) in UIViewController1 and now trying to use in UIViewController2.
This is how I am adding search controller:

```
DefinesPresentationContext = true;
_searchController = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null)
{
    WeakDelegate = this, DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false, WeakSearchResultsUpdater = this,
};
_searchController.SearchBar.SizeToFit();
_searchController.SearchBar.TintColor = UIColor.Black;
_searchController.SearchBar.WeakDelegate = this;
_searchController.SearchBar.OnEditingStarted += OnEditingStarted;
_searchController.SearchBar.OnEditingStopped += OnEditingStopped;
_searchController.SearchBar.SearchButtonClicked += OnSearchButtonClicked;
_searchController.SearchBar.CancelButtonClicked += OnSearchCancelledClicked;
_searchController.HidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;

NavigationController.NavigationBar.TopItem.TitleView = this._searchController.SearchBar;
_searchController.SearchBar.BecomeFirstResponder();
```

`OnSearchCancelledClicked` I am trying to remove the UISearchController

```
NavigationController.NavigationBar.TopItem.TitleView = null;
_searchController.SearchBar.ResignFirstResponder();
_searchController.SearchBar.RemoveFromSuperview();
```

What could be issue. Is the Search controller from the previous screen is still active and blocking calls to search controller in the new screen. If I directly navigate to UIViewController2 then search controller isworking fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue by setting the property in a new thread like below:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        _searchController.SearchBar.BecomeFirstResponder();
    });
});
```